# Unable to create a Dropdownlist that contains key and values in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup, excel-2016

I'm having trouble creating a dropdownlist that contains a name and a value for each column.

What I want to achieve is to use the dropdownlist that shows a bunch of names, but I want those names to have a 
value, so that I can use it (value) in macro. 
For exmple, when I select a name called "Joe" it will consists of the value 25 and will
be outputted as 25.

I've Googled around for some tutorials, but most of it wasn't useful. I've pasted the the img. I want to create a drown from this 
Bakers name and value. But have no clue to how I can make this possible.

Some examples or tips would be great! I would love to hear from you.[image]

Comment: Is locking cells what you need? Have you tried it? How this value should be output?

Comment: Actually, I'm a total noob with Excel stuffs. But what I want to do is show the  names as a list (Example: name1, name2 ...)
I have this separate sheet that contains the values for the list and was able to display them. But the problem is I want to use the 
names value (Ex. name = name1, value = 1) in macro. After selecting the name in macro I want to get the value and not the name. But I'm totally 
lost with how to combine? the values to names. Simply, I want the name column to have or hold the value so I can use it in macro for exporting the values to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the macro code:

```
Sub findValue()

Dim s As String
Dim value As Integer
Dim namesList As Range

Set namesList = Range("G3:G8") 'here you have to specify your range with names

s = InputBox("Enter the name: ")
'now you find the entered value (held in s variable) and get the value of a cell which
'is right to cell found (Offset function, then applied Value property)
value = namesList.Find(s).Offset(0, 1).Value

MsgBox "Found value is " & value

'save found value into the file
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oFile As Object
Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(yourPath) 'don't forget to enter full path to the
                                         'text file here!!
oFile.WriteLine value
oFile.Close
Set fso = Nothing
Set oFile = Nothing

End Sub
```

Now, the value is stored under `value` variable, you can do what you want with it :)

Comment: Thank you, but can how I call or  use findValue() ?  I'm currently , displaying only the names in the droplist.

Comment: Just copy in VBA environment in Excel. Then you can run it.

Comment: Thank you but there are multiple problems I'm messed up with.
(1. With block error showed up. (2nd day to touch VBA.)
(2. I do not understand why I should insert a value in the dialog.
(3. What I want to do. When I select for example "name1" and press the save to file button. I want the macro side to get the value 1 instead of name1.

Comment: The dialog box is just for convenience. You can enter any way you want it. Also added saving functionality now. Just place your path in there and it will work.

Comment: What is this type does not match error in "Set namesList = range("A3:A8")"?

Comment: Try `Range` instead of `range`.